# How to send agents through one resource in a sequence

Tags: anylogic

I have different types of agent in my logic and they utilize the same resource 'soldering station' which can only take one agent at a time. I want the resource to be allocated to each agent in a sequence like Agent A,B,A,B,A,B. Later I want the same station to do a assembly task as soon as agent A and B arrives.

I tried having 2 seize block and keeping same resource for both of them but the resource at times get alloted to only 1 type of agent continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that agents arrive in your `Seize` block in an ABAB sequence. You can do that by using a `Wait` block beforehand and manually `wait.free(...)` agents by their type. i.e. if an A agent just released the resource, make it tell a B agent to `wait.free(...)` so it can now use the `Seize` block...

Comment: I used two wait blocks and connected them through the release block of each other., but now how do I make the first agent pass through the first wait block? Thank you, Benjamin.

Comment: I also tried putting wait.free in Maing: On Startup(error); I tried putting it in a button for the first agent to pass through wait block 1.